# Prove if the determinant of a matrix is positive, then it has a Cholesky factorization

Tags: determinant

Prove if the determinant of a matrix is positive, then it has a Cholesky factorization.

A cholesky factorization can only be performed for hermitian, positive definite matrices. Should I go about proving that if the determinant of a matrix is zero, then that matrix is positive definite&hermitian? This seems circuitous. Anyone have other suggestions?

Comment: It is wrong, $\begin{bmatrix} -1 & \\ & -1 \end{bmatrix}$ doesn't have a cholesky decomposition.

Comment: I think I am also supposed to assume the matrix is hermitian and positive definite. How would you go about proving in this case?

Comment: than it is true. Hermitian and positive definite implies positive determinant. The converse is wrong.